# Bind callback function data to a button in Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, data-binding, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 and trying to implement a form that has a date and time field.

I'm using ionic-native `DatePicker` to implement a calender that users can choose from.

My js file is as such:

```
import {DatePicker} from 'ionic-native';
constructor() {
  this.startD = "starting";
}
datePickerFrom(){
    let options = {
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date'
    }
  
    function onSuccess(date){
      console.log("Selected date: " = date)
      this.startD = date;
    }
  
    function onError(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  
    DatePicker.show(options, onSuccess, onError);
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div>
      <button (click)="datePickerFrom()">S: {{startD}}</button>
      <button (click)="timePickerFrom()">T: {{startT}}</button>
  </div>
```

[image: This is how it looks when i start up the app]

This is how it looks when i start up the app.

However, when i click on the button to run `datePickerFrom()`, I can get the selected date `Selected date: Sat May 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT)` but get a **syntax error** when trying to bind the selected date (`this.startD`) to display as a placeholder value on the button.

> Error in Success callbackId: DatePickerPlugin1074986803 : TypeError:
> Cannot set property 'startD' of undefined. 
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'startD' of undefined

May I know if there's any way to work around in Ionic 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an arrow functions to be able to use the contextual this:

```
datePickerFrom() {
  let options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date'
  }

  DatePicker.show(options, (date) => {
    console.log("Selected date: " = date)
    this.startD = date;
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Otherwise (with fat functions), `this` doesn't correspond to the component instance.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Now what i have is: I can select the date and press ok. My console.log prints out the selected date but the placeholder value on my button does not change immediately. `this.startD` will only run after i click on another button or any other input fields and then the placeholder value changes.